# Can I leave PhD after two years to join a company?

Tags: phd, job

I'm from Africa. I came to the US three years ago to do my doctoral studies. Now, I am thinking of leaving my PhD, as I have found a two-year contract management job in Texas. Could you please advise me whether I should continue my PhD or join the company in Texas?

Comment: There is no way random people on the internet can give you useful advice on this. You need to talk to people who understand the details of your situation.

Comment: Two years and then what?

Comment: Hi henning -- reinstate Monica. With those two years of experience in Texas, I can find my next job.

Comment: Can you legally work full time in the US?

Comment: Just keep in mind that finishing your PhD would give you an advantage on the job market for the rest of your professional life, it's an investment for the future. Don't make the mistake to only compare your income now vs. in this job. Think about it this way: a few years from now, what would be a better asset on your resume: having a PhD or having this job experience?

Answer (score 5):

Can you quit a PhD? sure.

Can you stay in the US and take a job? probably not.

Unless you got into the US because of a family member or similar, your visa/status in the US is almost certainly tied to your PhD position. Unless your new employer is willing and able to sponsor you for a visa, quitting your PhD will likely mean having to leave the US.